# Why nhibernate session factory need to be set in as ThreadStaticSessionContext in NserviceBus?

Tags: nhibernate, nservicebus

I tried searching online about why we need to set nhibernate session factory as "ThreadStaticSessionContext" in NServiceBus, but i failed.

If i don't set it to "ThreadStaticSessionContext", it says "current_session_context_class" is not set. Anyone know why we need to set as "ThreadStaticSessionContext" ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with NServiceBus but I'm assuming it uses NHibernate [Contextual Sessions](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-current-session).  This allows for session management based on certain contexts.

The **ThreadStaticSessionContext** basically ensures you don't try to use the same session across multiple threads.